# Need advice on replacing a load bearing steel column/ post

Tags: load-bearing, post, old-house

In the 1960’s my house was remodeled. A load bearing wall was removed and replaced with an I beam. Eventually, I will be rebuilding the former wall to load bearing specs again, but also leaving the I beam. On the ground floor, everything is flat and level. Once you go to the upstairs hallway things get funky. The hallway is definitely higher on one side. You can see and feel it. So I’ve been working on removing the 60’s plaster drop ceiling and the crumbling 1914 original ceiling. Both are down now and I can see all of the joists and beam. I threw my laser level up to the top lip of the I-beam and noticed that the last 1/4 left side of the beam is high by about 1/2” or so.

[image: plan view of the floor joists and profile view of the bent beam]

The steel post is too tall, which is pushing the joists up directly underneath the upstairs hallway creating my issue. I’d love to rectify this while I have everything exposed. All load bearing walls in my house continue straight down to the foundation through masonry walls. Basically, my basement has the same layout as the first floor but with masonry walls. So the steel post goes through the subfloor and rests on one of these walls.

Here is the post in question:

[image: steel post embedded in a stud framed wall]

My thinking was to bring a screw Jack post to the next joist over/ a few more around the area, bring it up to height + a hair extra, taking the load off the existing post that is too high. Then to remove and swap out the original post with one that is the correct height. Then just slowly bring the temporary post/s down resting the beam on a new post set to the correct height.

1. Would this be a viable option/ the correct course of action?
2. What type of column/ post should I be looking for that is rated for permanent installation?
3. The fact that the deflection in the beam doesn’t travel/ distribute through the whole beam seems strange to me… does this matter?

Comment: A picture of the steel support post would be nice.  Quite a few have a screw adjustment on top, usually because people make mistakes and saves having to have different lengths.

Comment: This post has no adjustment. It is just a hollow steel post with a flange at the top and bottom. The bottom is resting on the basement masonry wall and the top is sitting directly under the beam

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sLMdAzt 
Pardon the dust… the bottom is almost impossible to get a photo of, however, it is basically the same. No adjustments

Comment: Note, if the steel beam is still in a good shape (no rust, no corrosion), the beam can be strengthened by adding the cover plate or web plates to eliminate the deflection. Since this is a load-bearing structure, please consult with a structural engineer before taking any action.

Comment: You probably should  have an engineer check(and plan the lowering)  that the post is too high(not another area too low).  Dropping a section of a house a 1/2 inch does need planing and time, maybe a month or more.

Comment: Your plan looks good, but the devil is in the details.  The first thing you need to do is figure out how much load that post is supporting.  From your sketches, it looks like it's supporting the weight of 1/4 of the house (first floor + second floor + roof, dead & live loads).  I bet you'll be surprised how much that is.  Then you need to size the temporary jack posts and the new replacement post accordingly.

Comment: What is the size (width and thickness of flanges plus height of beam) ?   What is length of beam (column to column) ?

Comment: What is length of floor joists on each side of steel beam?

Comment: Please verify that there is a flange between the bottom of the beam and top of column. It appears that there is a gap and there is a light colored chip wedged in the gap.

Comment: Are the tops of the floor joists above the top of the steel beam or equal to it?